# Doctrine EntityRepository, query a ManyToMany relation by an array

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have an entity, `Offer`, with a ManyToMany relationship to a `Country` Entity (i.e. an offer can be available on many countries)

```
Class Offer 
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Country")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="offer_cc",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cc", referencedColumnName="cc")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $countries;
}
```

And I want to query for all offers which have a country of a given array.

An image to better understand:

[image]

In this case, It should show only Offer 1 and Offer 2 because the former has Andorra and the latter has Italy.

From the form I have an ArrayCollection of Country entities.

Is it possible to do this in a EntityRepository with a query builder?

---

For example, this is how I filter by payoutMode, which is a simple int value:

```
class OfferRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllFiltered(array $filter = [])
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('offer');

        // Show only active offers
        $qb->where('offer.status=1');

        if($filter['payoutMode'] ?? null) {
            $qb->andWhere("offer.payoutMode = :payoutMode")->setParameter(':payoutMode', $filter['payoutMode']);
        }

        // TODO add filter by cc, category, tags

        return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```

Here, `$filter['countries']` contains:

```
ArrayCollection {#748 ▼
  -elements: array:2 [▼
    0 => Country {#762 ▼
      -cc: "AD"
    }
    1 => Country {#769 ▼
      -cc: "IT"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: We need the code that handles the filter form and the one that makes query based on these filters.

Comment: I added the repository code

Answer (score 1):

In DQL you there is `IN` function which can takes as right-side argument an array of IDs or array of entities. Use it for `JOIN` condition

Since you already get `ArrayList` of `Country` entities, it could be something like this:

```
class OfferRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllFiltered(array $filter = [])
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('offer');

        // Show only active offers
        $qb->where('offer.status=1');

        if($filter['payoutMode'] ?? null) {
            $qb->join("offer.payoutMode = :payoutMode")->setParameter(':payoutMode', $filter['countries']);
        }

        if(!empty($filter['payoutMode'])) {
             $qb->join('offer.countries', 'c', Expr\Join::WITH, 'c IN :countries')
                ->setParameter(':countries', $filter['countries']);
        }
        // TODO add filter by cc, category, tags

        return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```

Code not tested, so I could mess something up with the DQL `JOIN` syntax.
I'm not sure if `'c IN :countries'` syntax in valid in this context.
But in general, this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:

```
if(count($filter['countries'] ?? [])) {
    $qb->leftJoin('offer.countries', 'countries')
       ->andWhere("countries IN (:ccs)")->setParameter(':ccs', $filter['countries']);
}
```